# NHibernate, Sqlite, missing tables and IOC fun

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, structuremap

I'm doing unit testing on a class library that uses NHibernate for persistence. NHibernate is using a Sqlite in-memory database for testing purposes. Under normal circumstances, it's easy to get StructureMap to kick out a session for me.

However, because I'm using the in-memory database to improve testing speed, I need to have a single session available for the duration of a test (because it blows the database away when I create a new one). And there is another wrinkle. The case that is currently burning me is testing a custom NHibernate-based ASP.NET membership provider. These are created apparently once per AppDomain, so I shouldn't inject the session into it, for obvious reasons.

Is there a way in structuremap to tell it to get rid of an instance of a particular type while still maintaining the bits that tell it how to instantiate that type? Really, if I could get away with it, I would just make it act like the HttpScoped object lifetime, but apparently I can only do that within the context of an Http request. Is there a straightforward way to manually control the lifetime of an object coming out of structuremap?

I apologize for the length of this and the possibility that it is a dumb question. I'm solo on this project, so I don't really have anyone to bounce ideas off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the session in your own ISession implementation which delegates to a real session which lifetime you control. Then register your own ISession as instance.

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as the fix, because it was the idea that led me to the idea I needed, which I'll explain below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making two constructors for my provider along with a private variable of type Func. By default, its value was set to my standard code for creating a session using StructureMap's ObjectFactory.

The overloaded constructor accepted as a parameter an object of type Func. That way, I can inject a strategy for creating an instance of that type if needed, but otherwise don't have to go through any extended effort. In the case of my test, I created the session in the NUnit setup method and destroyed it in the Teardown. I don't love this idea, but I don't currently hate it enough to rip it out....yet.

This got rid of the error I was experiencing in regard to the tables. However, it appears that NHibernate for some reason cannot write to an in-memory sqlite database under the conditions I created. I'm now working on testing to see if I can write to one in the file system. It isn't ideal, but it will be a good long while (I hope), before the performance of writing to disk really starts hurting.